# uniform continuity of $e^{-x^2}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

How to show uniform continuity of $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$?

I saw something about $e^{-x}$. But not sure how I should go with $e^{-x^2}$.

$$|e^{-y^2}-e^{-x^2}|=\cdots$$

Please help.

Comment: Use the mean value theorem and the fact that the derivative is bounded.

Comment: Any continuous function on $\mathbb R$ that $\to 0$ at $\pm \infty$ is uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=\exp(-x^2)$. By the MVT, there is $z$ between $x$ and $y$ such that
$$
f(y)-f(x)=(y-x)f'(z)=(y-x)[-2z\exp(-z^2)].
$$
Now using $\exp(z^2)\geq z^2+1=|z|^2+1\geq2|z|$, we have
$$
|2z\exp(-z^2)|=\frac{2|z|}{\exp(z^2)}\leq\frac{2|z|}{|z|^2+1}\leq 1.
$$
Thus, $|f(y)-f(x)|\leq|y-x|$ and the claim follows.